# Get store view attribute value from collection

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-collection

I'm using the following call to get a product collection:

```
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('attribute_name1','attribute_name2'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
```

The product "attribute_name1" has never been set on the default view of the product in Magento admin, but it has been set on the store view level.

If I call the attribute in my code with `$product->getAttributeName1()` it returns null - even if a value has been set on the store view level in admin.

If I set the default value of the attribute to "foo" and the store view value af the attribute to "bar" the call `$product->getAttributeName1()` returns "bar" as expected.

My questions is: How can I structure my collection call to ensure that my `$product->getAttributeName1()` call returns the store view level value, even if a default value hasn't been set?

Answer (score 2):

You can load each product with `$product->load()`, but you will kill your website performance.

Use the following raw attribute access code:

```
$myValue = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
  ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'my_attribute_name', $storeId);
```

It will be much much faster ;) 
(of course depending on the number of attribute you need to load )

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was wondering if there was a way to add the values to the initial collections call, to avoid the additional db queries with the getAttributeRawValue()

Comment: addAttributeToSelect should work, try debugging your query with getSelect to understand why it is not adding your two attributes.

Comment: Also try to call "$collection->load()", I'm not sure that additional attributes are loaded within an iterator.

Comment: They are added as expected. The issue is that they are only added if a default value is made on the product attribute. If the default value isn't set, but a store view value is, the value is not added to the collection.

Comment: A default value should always exists. Let me guess... did you use Magmi as product importer?

Comment: It is a common issue on mass importers. Try just opening one product on your backend and save it without modifying anything. If for that product you correctly see the two attributes the problem is here.

Comment: No, added directly from admin. The scope of the attribute is store, that means you can set it directly on store without default. It can be solved by changing the attribute scope, but that doesn't give me all the flexibility I wanted...

Comment: Even on store scope Magento should save a default value AFAIK. I suggest you to fix it by defining a dummy default value with "Mage::getModel("catalog/product_action")->updateAttributes()".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php 
$storeID = 3;  // Your store id here.
$store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeID);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('attribute_name1','attribute_name2'));
$collection->addStoreFilter($store);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));

foreach($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getSku().'=>'.$product->getAttributeName1();
    echo '<br>';
    echo $product->getSku().'=>'.$product->getAttributeName2();
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the product collection with few attribute, for a specific store view scope, then this code snippet is helpful for you.

```
$storeId=1; //YOUR STORE VIEW ID.
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
              ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','ATTRIBUTE_NAME1','ATTRIBUTE_NAME2'));
foreach($collection as $product){
    echo "Product Name: ".$product->getName();
    echo "Product Name: ".$product->getATTRIBUTE_NAME1();
}
```